# Why my array works anew after restart activity?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I use *onSaveInstanceState* and *onRestoreInstanceState* to save picture position in array after restart activity. But it doesn't work - after restart activity array works anew, what is the problem?

```
int[] array_images = {
            R.drawable.p_orange,
            R.drawable.p_banana,
            R.drawable.p_apple,
    };
    int index = -1;
private void updateImage()
  {
    index++;
    if(index >= array_images.length)
      index = 0;
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(array_images[index]);
  }

@Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    outState.putIntArray("array_images", array_images);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

  }
  @Override
  public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    array_images = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("array_images");

  }
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          dialog.dismiss();
          finish();
          startActivity(getIntent());
          updateImage();
        }

      });
```

Comment: once you restore the array , call `updateImage()`.

Answer (score 2):

In `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` only the values will be restored, but your views will be recreated. So you have to set all the values to views once you restore the values in `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` or even you can do it in `onCreate()`, you will receive the saved bundle in `onCreate()` too.

Comment: after `setContentView()` in oncreate(), you can check if bundle is null and if it is not null assign the value from the bundle to your array.